# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
return ListTile(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade300)),
                title: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
                subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['price']),
                leading: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.network(documentSnapshot['image']), //i got error here to display the product in my shopping cart because i display multiple images
                ),
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Firestore? It seems like `image` is a list from the error.

Comment: You will have to use a builder to get the index. then you can display each image by index documentSnapshot['index']['image']

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount : documentSnapshot.length,
  itemBuilder:(context, index) {
    return ListTile(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade300)),
                title: Text(documentSnapshot[index]['name']),
                subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot[index]['price']),
                leading: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.network(documentSnapshot[index]['image']),
                );
  }
);
```

The error basically you're getting because you're receiving list of data from your database and you're trying to assign them as a single data. It won't be possible.